# Abort ArrayEach callback in jsonparser early

Tags: go

Looking at this [callback](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser/blob/5048f353608edffd70b6532f2a0c8b0ccd36df12/parser.go#L412) (line 412), is it possible to break out of the callback loop from inside the callback function itself? Or would I need to wrap it or extend it in some way to create that capability?

This is the code:

```
jsonparser.ArrayEach(data, func(value []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int, err error) {
    if v, err := jsonparser.GetUnsafeString(value, "username"); nil == err && v == lookFor {
        z = v
        return // Abort in some way?
    }
})
```

The library is still waiting for a *query-like* update so for now this is the cheapest way to find a value, which still outperforms any full `json` parser by far (doing about 9.21x to 9.38x faster on benchmarks). So I'm kind of aiming for a `LIMIT 1`-ish solution.

I was thinking of doing a full copy-paste and making an cloned version on the interface and making..

```
if t != NotExist {
    cb(v, t, o, e)
}
```

into...

```
if t != NotExist {
    boolVal = cb(v, t, o, e) // Extending it to have a return value
}
```

... return a `boolean` and validate as a continue indicator. But would there be a more clean way without fully duplicating this code?

Comment: The only thing you could do is panic and recover it yourself, but depending on your use case, it may not be any faster.

Comment: You think letting this just run it's course (let's say on 1M+ JSON records, so a vast amount of bytes) won't hurt performance?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell from the context here. If aborting the stack from your entrypoint is OK, you can have your callback panic, and you can recover. A panic and recover isn't cheap, but yes, it probably a lot cheaper than parsing 1M json record.

Comment: In Objective-C I would solve this by using a `__block BOOL done` for example and check if it was done. Still causing the loops, but at least preventing the full value comparison to be executed. Is this possible in Go?

Comment: I think I managed it by just using a boolean on the same scope-level. I didn't know they could be accessed inside a callback scope too. Lol now I feel silly :P. Went from `67498865 ns/op` to `37491376 ns/op` in the benchmark.